# Editor only view in XCode

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I am using swiftUI to write a new app. Every-time I open a new file the Canvas opens up.
I want the default view to be "Only Editor" and I can open the canvas whenever I want to manually.

Is there a way to change the default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can select "show editor only" via Xcode, this will always open the Editor, check the  screenshot

Adjust Editor Option ---- show editor only

or Select any SwiftUI file then press Command + Enter(Return key) this will select the show editor only option.

[image]

Comment: I do this everytime I open up a new file. Wanted to know if this could be the default. I don't like the Canvas all the time.

Comment: @thenakulchawla could be an Xcode bug but I am not facing any issue.

Comment: I did it. Multiple times, started XCode again but the new files still open up with Canvas. Frustrating.Maybe it is an Xcode. Will see today, if I am still facing the issue, I will file a bug.

Comment: Same here, drives me crazy. You can uncheck "Canvas" and Hit "Show editor only", but the next time a SwiftUI View file opens, e.g. when hitting a breakpoint while debugging, the Canvas is right back there.

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck `Canvas` as shown below and this state will persists and for new files and after Xcode restart. (Tested with Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

**Caution: Without Canvas opened SwiftUI contextual menu items are not available in Editor. Just be aware.**

Comment: let me try it. I did it. Multiple times, started XCode again but the new files still open up with Canvas. Frustrating.